# How do I replicate this try/except for all other inputs in the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

How do I replicate the same try/except you see for the first input in every other input?

```
import math
import sys
import time

while True: 
    try:
        Money = float(input("How much are you depositing?"))
    except:
        print("please enter numbers")
        continue         
    AIR = float(input("What is the annual interest rate?"))
    #Annual Interest Rate
    n = int(input("How many times a year do you want the interst compounded for?"))
    # number of times the interst compounds
    t = int(input("How many years are you investing/borrowing the money?"))
    # total number of years the money is being invested/borrowed for
    CCI = Money *(1+AIR/n)**(n*t)
    # Calculated Compound Interest
    print(math.trunc(CCI));
    # main program
```

Comment: What do you mean by replicate? Please elaborate?

Comment: So when you run the program it starts by asking "How much are you depositing?" I put the try except block there so that only numbers were allowed to be entered and it would continue giving the user a retry of the question until they entered a valid input, then it moves to the next question. I need help in creating the same try except to do the same thing for all the other questions (inputs in the code).

Comment: I hope i'm making sense here?

Answer (score 4):

Extract that logic into a function which you can then reuse:

```
def read(type_, prompt):  # using "type_" not to shadow built-in "type"
    while True:
        try:
            return type_(input(prompt))
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            print("Please enter a {}".format(type_.__name__))

Money = read(float, "How much are you depositing?\n")
AIR = read(float, "What is the annual interest rate?\n")
n = read(int, "How many times a year do you want the interst compounded for?\n")
t = read(int, "How many years are you investing/borrowing the money?\n")

CCI = Money *(1+AIR/n)**(n*t)
print(math.trunc(CCI))
```

Comment: I tend to disagree, unless they haven't learned about functions yet. This is much neater, more readable and will not require to enter all values again if you just had a typo on let's say the last one.

Answer (score 1):

you can add them in the same try-except or write multiple times. if you do it in same you will be having the same error message but If you write multiple try-except then you can have different error messages

```
import math
import sys
import time

while True: 
            try:
                Money = float(input("How much are you depositing?"))
                n = int(input("How many times a year do you want the interst compounded for?"))
                # number of times the interst compounds
                t = int(input("How many years are you investing/borrowing the money?"))
 
                AIR = float(input("What is the annual interest rate?"))
                #Annual Interest Rate
            
           
            except:
                print("please enter numbers")
                continue         
            # total number of years the money is being invested/borrowed for
            CCI = Money *(1+AIR/n)**(n*t)
            # Calculated Compound Interest
            print(math.trunc(CCI));
            # main program
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

app.py

```
while True: 
        try:
            Money = float(input("How much are you depositing?"))
            AIR = float(input("What is the annual interest rate?"))
            #Annual Interest Rate
            n = int(input("How many times a year do you want the interst compounded for?"))
            # number of times the interst compounds
            t = int(input("How many years are you investing/borrowing the money?")) 
            # total number of years the money is being invested/borrowed for
            CCI = Money *(1+AIR/n)**(n*t)
            # Calculated Compound Interest
            print(math.trunc(CCI));
            # main program
            break
        except:
            print("please enter numbers")money?"))
```

The `break` tells python to get out of the loop

so if the code reaches `break` it means that it didn't throw any exceptions and that it is indeed a number

You put all your calculations in the try block so that it throws an exception when there's a mistake